# Perl try catch for user defined exceptions

Tags: perl

I want to know if perl has some try catch mechanism similar to python where i can raise user defined exceptions and handle accordingly.

**PythonCode:**

```
   try:
       number = 6
       i_num = 3
       if i_num < number:
           raise ValueTooSmallError
       elif i_num > number:
           raise ValueTooLargeError
       break
   except ValueTooSmallError:
       print("This value is too small, try again!")
       print()
   except ValueTooLargeError:
       print("This value is too large, try again!")
       print()
```

I know perl has try catch mechnism like below:

```
sub method_one {
    try {
        if ("number" eq "one") {
            die("one");
        } else {
            die("two");
        }
    } catch {
        if ($@ eq "one") {
            print "Failed at one";
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
eval {
    open(FILE, $file) || 
      die MyFileException->new("Unable to open file - $file");
  };

  if ($@) {
    # now $@ contains the exception object of type MyFileException
    print $@->getErrorMessage();  
    # where getErrorMessage() is a method in MyFileException class
  }
```

I am concentrating more on the **if** checks on the catch. Is there a way i can avoid the checks for the different kind of errors i catch.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Class#SYNOPSIS

Comment: Note it's better to use the pattern `eval {...; 1} or do {...}` instead of `eval {...}; if ($@) {...}` (even though you will still find many examples of the latter online). [See also](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1153468)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest solution is probably the straight-forward [failures](http://p3rl.org/failures) object and [TryCatch](http://p3rl.org/TryCatch) for the type checking.

```
use failures qw(
    Example::Value_too_small
    Example::Value_too_large
);
use TryCatch;

try {
    my $number = 6;
    my $i_num = 3;
    if ($i_num < $number) {
        failure::Example::Value_too_small->throw({
            msg => '%d is too small, try again!',
            payload => $i_num,
        });
    } elsif ($i_num > $number) {
        failure::Example::Value_too_large->throw({
            msg => '%d is too large, try again!',
            payload => $i_num,
        });
    }
} catch (failure::Example::Value_too_small $e) {
    say sprintf $e->msg, $e->payload;
} catch (failure::Example::Value_too_large $e) {
    say sprintf $e->msg, $e->payload;
} finally {
    ...
}
```

You can upgrade from here to [custom::failures](http://p3rl.org/custom::failures), [Throwable](http://p3rl.org/Throwable), [Exception::Class](http://p3rl.org/Exception::Class).

Answer (score 1):

Like @daxim pointed out, there is [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch), but I am writing this for all those who would see this and to alert them that unfortunately [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) is now broken since the version 0.006020 of [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare) on which [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) relies.

In replacement, there is [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) which is quite unique and provides all the features like in other programming languages.

It supports exception variable assignment, exception class like the OP requested, clean-up with `finally` block, embedded try-catch blocks.

Full disclosure: I have developed Nice::Try when [TryCatch got broken](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=97089).